# node-red variable assignment

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have a debug node that can correctly print

```
msg.payload.tns:Envelope.tns:Body[0].WX:RetrieveClaimDetailsResponse[0].WX:claimFolder[0].WX:underlyingAgreements[0].WX:policyNumber
```

(I've used a xml node to convert from xml to json)

but in a function node, I can't assign this value to a variable

I thought I could try something like

```
var policyNumber = msg.payload.["tns:Envelope"].["tns:Body"][0];// (...)
```

but I am getting a syntax error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually use

```
var policyNumber = msg.payload["tns:Envelope"]["tns:Body"][0];
```